# Accessing Child in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "14 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94105, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "23 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.3 mi",
                  "value" : 2060
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "7 mins",
                  "value" : 444
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "6 mins",
                  "value" : 344
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I have been attempting to access the "text" value of duration_in_traffic and to store that value into a variable. For some reason I am getting the value to be undefined.

```
var hold = JSON.parse(body.rows.elements.duration.text);
```

Why cannot I access the child like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested arrays, so you need to access the elements in the arrays by their index.

```
var hold = body.rows[0].elements[0].duration_in_traffic.text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I tried accessing by index and the error returned was `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Looks like I solved the problem. The object body itself as not reading properly unless I JSON parsed it and put it into a variable. `var holder = JSON.parse(body);` then `var hold = holder.rows[0].elements[0].duration_in_traffic.text;`

Comment: @Katserbot "some strange reason"? That's the whole point of `JSON.parse`, to convert a JSON string into an object so you can work with it in Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar it was strange because of I had JSON parsed the object earlier in the function to access a different child. That language has been removed for future views.

Comment: If you used the same variable that you parsed it into earlier, it should have worked. You must have overwritten the variable.

Comment: @Barmar it was an issue with the variable name itself, it was being reused.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the JSON string (if it is a string) first, then you can access it ... assuming `body` is the var that holds the **string**, you would do

```
var hold = JSON.parse(body).rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
```

or

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
var hold = obj.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse does not parse part of a json string. if your json string is store in body for example, you need to parse it first:

```
var jsonObj  = JSON.parse(body);
```

This will give you a javascript object to work with, then you can access the properties of the object as you have tried to do.

```
var hold = body.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; //similar to @js91
```

Hope that helps!